# Heroku H12 timeout issue with no recovery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout

We are running 3 2X dynos on heroku using rails 4. Every few days, H12 (request timeout) errors start to occur and the app never recovers. It must be restarted in order to function again.

I noticed this morning that this started happening while the database was backing up  (using heroku postgres as the database). It would be ok if on occasion timeouts happened during backup. It is easy to understand the database being busy. But, the problem is the app never recovers after the backup completes. Every page request from that point forward generates an H12 error.

Heroku has no helpful advice.

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace of the error, and does it says "completed" after the h12 error?